# How to update newly added rows in mysql database excluding already updated rows using python pandas

Tags: python, mysql, linux, pandas

I have the below code which updates the mysql database batchwise.

```
count = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM table",con=db)
count = count.iat[0,0]
batchsize = 1000
for offset in range(0,count,batchsize):
    df = pd.read_sql(('SELECT id,col2,col3 FROM table LIMIT %s OFFSET %s' 
                      % (batchsize,offset)), con=db)
    ## code ##
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("UPDATE table SET col2=%s, col3=%s WHERE id=%s",d)
    db.commit()
db.close()
```

After updating, later if new records got added in mysql database, those has to be updated by running the same script. The code is ran on linux environment as python script.

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you looking for something to happen as soon as a new row is added? I.e. a trigger. Why would something need to be updated as soon as added, surely the adding process should also adjust the record.

Comment: No @AndyG, not as soon as new row added. But after some new records are added, then if we run the script only those new records should be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [pickle file](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-pickle-module-save-objects-serialization/) to save the count of rows of a table. Each time I run the script, I read the row count(which was updated in last execution) from pickle file and start the execution from there. My updated code looks like this:

```
count = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM table",con=db)
count = count.iat[0,0]
start = None
with open("pickle_file_name.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    start = pickle.load(f)
batchsize = 1000
for offset in range(start,count,batchsize):
    df = pd.read_sql(('SELECT id,col2,col3 FROM table LIMIT %s OFFSET %s' 
                      % (batchsize,offset)), con=db)
    ## code ##
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("UPDATE table SET col2=%s, col3=%s WHERE id=%s",d)
    db.commit()
with open("pickle_file_name.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(count, f)
db.close()
```

In this way I can always save the row count in the pickle file and start from that count to update the newly added rows by executing the same script.